# How do i make it so that a certain input lists the functions and a certain input calls one of them?

Tags: c++

You know how this shows up when you choose a directory in the terminal?

[image: choosing a directory on terminal]

Is there a way I could create my own version of this, but when the user chooses one of the choices, it calls a function?

*i mean nothing about the terminal or directory, i am using it as an example*

user types
`"menu"`

and there'd be a list of words that show up

`"games"`
`"text"`
`"about"`

user can type

`"open games"`

and it runs the function i named games

here are my test functions:

```
void game()
{
    cout << "you are in game"
}

void text()
{
    cout << "you are in text"
}

void about()
{
    cout << "you are in about"
```

how do i make it so that a certain input LISTS the different functions, and a certain input CALLS the different functions?

Comment: You could write your own shell.

Comment: Why before `main()` actually?? What you're describing is a shell feature, so it's unclear what you want to do. Passing the choice to your programs command line parameters maybe? These can be inspect using the  `argc` and `argv` parameters, when your main function is called.

Comment: Well you have to write that yourself - parse input, produce output.

Comment: This is not a feature the language provides.  If you want to provide interactive text menus then you'll need to write code to do it.  Read a line, parse it, then call the appropriate functions based on the input.

Comment: not clear what you mean by "choose"

Comment: @NeilButterworth i mean if you see the list of choices, you could enter a specific input and it "chooses" that option and runs the function according to it.

Comment: All in all it is not clear what you want to do. Things for you to look into are [<filesystem>])(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) to get lists of directory and file names. You will need to be able to show them to the user and let the user select one of them. And based on the input choose a function to call.

Comment: there is no list of choices - there are names of things in the filesystem

Comment: @NeilButterworth It appears that some of the names are "magic".  OP really needs to explain what they want in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have understood that you want to see a list of functions in your program, not files on your hard disk.

There's no built-in way to do this, and although I can think of some more clever ways to do it, they are beyond your current level of understanding.

Therefore, I recommend doing it the simple and stupid way:

```
while(true) {
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);
    if(input == "open games")
        games();
    else if(input == "open text")
        text();
    else if(input == "open about")
        about();
    else if(input == "options")
        cout << "games text about\n";
    else
        cout << "unknown command\n";
}
```

Comment: and where wouild this code  be placed?  this is not a great answer

Comment: @NeilButterworth in the place where you want the program to wait for commands and run them

Comment: but what is this program? how and when does it run?

Comment: @NeilButterworth it's the one the asker is trying to write. Do you expect every answer to contain the basics of "how do I make a program?"

Comment: in general no, but in this case yes - it seems like the OP wants to display some options when doing something like cd'ing into a directory  i agree the question is very vague and should have been closed.

Comment: I don't think this works - you can't introspect the list of accepted inputs (for `options`)

Comment: @MSalters `cout << "games text about\n";` - no introspection is *necessary*. Even though it is helpful, I think it is beyond the asker's level. You are welcome to write your own answer, as you have done.

Comment: this answer is what i was looking for. sorry for the vague question, i didn't know how to word it. i meant like HOW the terminal does that for listing your directories and you could pick it. the answer i wanted had nothing to do with the directories at all. i was giving an example of something that did what i was looking to do.

Comment: @bleachedb the terminal commands are more complicated because the options can change. In your program the options don't change, which is why I suggest doing it the really easy way :)

Comment: @user253751 thank you, i am okay with doing something with indefinite choices. i only have a few choices and if i plan on them being able to change, i should probably try to learn more about c++ before i do that.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two wishes: you want to store a list of functions with names, and in addition you want to be able to retrieve the whole list of names.

The type that you probably want is `std::map<std::string, std::function<void(void)>>`.

E.g.

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<void(void)>> options;
options["game"] = game;
```

`std::map` stores key-value pairs. The key here is the string, the value is the function. You can iterate over `options` and print all the keys. See your C++ book for more details.